# How can @PropertySource access proteced remote properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-config

I have this in my client project to grab a specific remote configuration file from `{application}/{profile}/path/to/file`:

```
@PropertySource(value = "http://user:xxx@localhost:8888/ConfigRepo/dev/main/db/database.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

The configuration file `http://user:xxx@localhost:8888/ConfigRepo/dev/main/db/database.properties` is provided by Spring Cloud Config Service and protected by Spring Security. I can access {application}{profile} from the regular cloud client setting, but by default it doesn't care other files under a sub-folder like `db/database.properties`, I have to explicitly use @PropertySource with a specific URI to access it.(Maybe I'm wrong?)

I have this configuration in my Spring cloud config service project:

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: user
      password: xxx
```

And Spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ConfigRepo").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Now, if I ran command `curl http://user:xxx@localhost:8888/ConfigRepo/dev/main/db/database.properties`, it will return the the properties properly. but the above `@PropertySource` will thows this error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://user:xxx@localhost:8888/ConfigRepo/dev/main/db/database.properties
```

I'm wondering how to make the Spring security accept basic authentication from `@PropertySource`? Or any other equivalen annotation allows me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To access the properties available on the Spring Cloud Configuration Server use dedicated properties instead of @PropertySource.

Step 1

Add this dependency to your application pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Step 2

Add following properties to your application.properties

```
spring.application.name=your-app
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://user:xxx@localhost:8888/
```

This will effectively import properties from http://user:xxx@localhost:8888/your-app/dev

Step 3

Use the properties from the server the same way as others. For example:

```
@Value("${your-property}")
```

(Based on [Baeldung Spring Cloud Configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration))

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can access the default remote configuration under the root of {application}/{profile}. I'm trying to access a specific file, locates at `{application}{profile}/path/to/file`, which not be imported by default, that's why I provide a full URI.

Comment: I found something about configuring a custom RestTemplate. Please check if it fits: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-rest-template

Comment: This must works, but it will make things complex. I'd like try simple solution first until cornered.